# delete rows from a table and an item from an ArrayList by pressing a button on the same line at runtime

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist

I will try to be as clear as possible

My problem is this, I have a screen with some fields and a table, by pressing Ok inserting rows in the table and items in an ArrayList at the same time.
This line has a ImageButton that is inserted along with the line. I need to click this button it delete the line and the respective item of Array. I tried a few things but without success. By pressing the ImageButton nothing happens.
Before I forget I'm using fragments.

This is my sceen:

http://snag.gy/l3FTW.jpg

My line layout

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bordas">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_animais"
        style="@style/TextoCorpoTabela" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_peso_bruto"
        style="@style/TextoCorpoTabela" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_peso_liquido"
        style="@style/TextoCorpoTabela" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_excluir"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_lixeira" />

</TableRow>
```

My onClick method

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    recebeValores();
    if (view == btOk) {
        if (verificaCampos()) {
            insereLinha();
            calculaTotal();
            limpaCampos();
            etNumeroTanque.setEnabled(false);
        }
    } else {
        if (view == btFinalizar) {
            //salvar();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack("Biometria").replace(R.id.principal, new BiometriaRelatorioFragment()).commit();
        } else {
            for (ItemBiometria itemBiometria : itemBiometriaArrayList) {
                if (view == itemBiometria.botaoExcluir) {
                    itemBiometriaArrayList.remove(itemBiometria);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My private class

```
private class ItemBiometria {
    private int animais;
    private float peso;
    private float pesoLiquido;
    private float tara;
    private View botaoExcluir;

    public int getAnimais() {
        return animais;
    }

    public void setAnimais(int animais) {
        this.animais = animais;
    }

    public float getPeso() {
        return peso;
    }

    public void setPeso(float peso) {
        this.peso = peso;
    }

    public float getPesoLiquido() {
        return pesoLiquido;
    }

    public void setPesoLiquido(float pesoLiquido) {
        this.pesoLiquido = pesoLiquido;
    }

    public float getTara() {
        return tara;
    }

    public void setTara(float tara) {
        this.tara = tara;
    }

    public View getBotaoExcluir() {
        return botaoExcluir;
    }

    public void setBotaoExcluir(View botaoExcluir) {
        this.botaoExcluir = botaoExcluir;
    }
}
```

My method insert lines in table

```
   public void insereLinha() {
    ItemBiometria itemBiometria = new ItemBiometria();

    TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) viewPai.findViewById(R.id.tl_biometria);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final TableRow novaLinha = (TableRow) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_linha_tabela_biometria, null);

    itemBiometria.setAnimais(Integer.valueOf(etAnimais.getText().toString()));
    itemBiometria.setPeso(Float.valueOf(etPeso.getText().toString()));
    itemBiometria.setTara(Float.valueOf(etTara.getText().toString()));

    TextView tvAnimais = (TextView) novaLinha.findViewById(R.id.tv_animais);
    tvAnimais.setText(animais);

    TextView tvPesoBruto = (TextView) novaLinha.findViewById(R.id.tv_peso_bruto);
    float peso = itemBiometria.getPeso();
    tvPesoBruto.setText(String.format("%.2f", peso));

    TextView tvPesoLiquido = (TextView) novaLinha.findViewById(R.id.tv_peso_liquido);
    float pesoLiquido = itemBiometria.getPeso() - itemBiometria.getTara();
    tvPesoLiquido.setText(String.format("%.2f", pesoLiquido));
    itemBiometria.setPesoLiquido(Float.valueOf(tvPesoLiquido.getText().toString()));

    ImageButton excluir = (ImageButton) novaLinha.findViewById(R.id.bt_excluir);
    excluir.setOnClickListener(this);
    itemBiometria.setBotaoExcluir(excluir);

    tableLayout.addView(novaLinha);
    itemBiometriaArrayList.add(itemBiometria);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i could solve my problem,
simply remove the onClick method, and pass a new OnClickListner to create the button:

```
     ImageButton excluir = (ImageButton) novaLinha.findViewById(R.id.bt_excluir);
    excluir.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            novaLinha.setVisibility(viewPai.GONE);
            for (ItemBiometria itemBiometria : itemBiometriaArrayList) {
                if (view == itemBiometria.getBotaoExcluir()) {
                    itemBiometriaArrayList.remove(itemBiometria);
                    break;
                }
            }
            calculaTotal();
        }
    });
    itemBiometria.setBotaoExcluir(excluir);
```